# Function from C# to C++ via Qt lib

Tags: qt

Could you tell me how these function from C# can be re-written to C++ via Qt lib?

```
private MemoryStream _memoryStream= new MemoryStream();
```

//WriteUTFBytes

```
public void WriteUTFBytes(string value)
{
    //Length - max 65536.
    UTF8Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] buffer = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(value);
    if (buffer.Length > 0)
    WriteBytes(buffer);
}
```

//WriteBytes

```
public void WriteBytes(byte[] buffer)
{

        for (int i = 0; buffer != null && i < buffer.Length; i++)
            _memoryStream.WriteByte(buffer[i]);
}
```

//WriteByte

```
public void WriteByte(int value)
    {
        _memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)value);
    }
```

//WriteShort

```
public void WriteShort(int value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)value);
        WriteBigEndian(bytes);
    }
```

//WriteBigEndian

```
private void WriteBigEndian(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
            return;
        for (int i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            _memoryStream.WriteByte(bytes[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private:
    QBuffer _buffer;

public:
    YourClass()
    {
        _buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    }

    void writeUtfBytes(const QString &value)
    {
        QTextStream ts(&_buffer);
        ts.setCodec("UTF-8");
        ts << value;
    }

    void writeBytes(const char *data, int size)
    {
        if (data)
            _buffer.write(data, size);
    }

    void writeByte(int value)
    {
        _buffer.putChar(value);
    }

    void writeShort(int value)
    {
        _buffer.putChar(value >> 8);
        _buffer.putChar((char) value);
    }
```